# CSS: Image - Float:Right is leaving a border around the image

Tags: css

I am trying to make image 'stick' to the right, but it is showing some sort of invisible border.

[image]

Things I have tried adding:

```
1) position: absolute;
2) border: 0; / border: 0px;
3) top: -5px; / I tried to put negative px, not even -1000px; has effect on it.
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img class="float-right" src="img/FacebookImageLoading.jpg" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
.float-right{
 float:right;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried padding??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue would be handy, but in the meantime, try:

```
html, body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to be of help.